# Como inserir itens de um arquivo JSON em uma tabela html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Tenho este arquivo JSON:

```
var identificacao = [

{
    "nome": "João Silva",
    "cpf":  "444.111.777-00",
    "rg": "44.66.55.00-1",
    "nascimento": "28/06/1994",
    "endereco": [{
        "rua": "Av. Marechal Tito",
        "numero": 155,
        "bairro": "Jardim do Vale",
        "cep": "08108-145",
        "cidade": "São Paulo",
        "estado": "SP",
        },
    ],
    "contato":[{
    "telefone": "2222-2222",
    "celular": "92222-2222",
    "email": "joaosilva@gmail.com"
},
],

    "renda": "5.000",
    "foto": "joao_silva.jpg",
    "conta":[{
        "banco": "Bradesco",
        "agencia": "05",
        "numero_da_conta": "0102-1"
    },]
},
```

que contem 5 itens, porem na minha tabela html o único que aparece é esse primeiro item.

No meu javascript usei este código:

```js
<script>
     $(function(){
             x = identificacao.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                
            var saida = "";
                
                 saida += "<tr>";
                 saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].nome+ "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].cpf + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].rg + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].nascimento + "</td>";
                
                 for(j=0; j< identificacao[i].endereco.length;j++){ 
                     
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].endereco[j].rua + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].endereco[j].numero + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].endereco[j].cep + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].endereco[j].bairro + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].endereco[j].cidade + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].endereco[j].estado + "</td>";
                 }
                
                 for(k=0; k< identificacao[i].contato.length;k++){
                     
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].contato[k].telefone + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].contato[k].celular + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].contato[k].email + "</td>";
                 }
               
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].renda + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].foto + "</td>";
                
                  for(n=0; n< identificacao[i].conta.length;n++){
                      
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].conta[n].banco + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].conta[n].agencia + "</td>";
                        saida += "<td>" + identificacao[i].conta[n].numero_da_conta + "</td>";
                }
                        
                       
                        saida += "</tr>";
                    
                    $("#tbody").append(saida);
                    $("#tabela").dataTable();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Gostaria de ajuda para saber qual erro estou cometendo, e como posso fazer para que todos meus itens apareçam na tabela.

Comment: Já tentou fazer com $.each?

Answer (score 1):

Tive alguns problemas para usar seu JSON. Recomendo utilizar o site jsonformatter
para formatar e validar a sua variável.

```
[
  {
    "nome":"João Silva",
    "cpf":"444.111.777-00",
    "rg":"44.66.55.00-1",
    "nascimento":"28/06/1994",
    "endereco":[
      {
        "rua":"Av. Marechal Tito",
        "numero":155,
        "bairro":"Jardim do Vale",
        "cep":"08108-145",
        "cidade":"São Paulo",
        "estado":"SP"
      }
    ],
    "contato":[
      {
        "telefone":"2222-2222",
        "celular":"92222-2222",
        "email":"joaosilva@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "renda":"5.000",
    "foto":"joao_silva.jpg",
    "conta":[
      {
        "banco":"Bradesco",
        "agencia":"05",
        "numero_da_conta":"0102-1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Minha primeira opção vai ser te recomendar o jPut: https://github.com/shabeer-ali-m/jput.
Você escrever um template e ele consegue consumir seu JSON para esse template.

Minha segunda recomendação vai ser essa:
http://jsfiddle.net/7MRx6/338/

É um código em JS que faz o que você quer, mas tem o problema de nos campos endereço, contato e conta, que são multivalorados, ele não imprimi muito bem. Logo recomendaria tratar seu JSON ou o código.

> Recomendações tiradas do próprio stackoverflow, da pergunta em inglês:
>
> convert-json-data-to-a-html-table

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um template da tabela e renderizar a partir do JSON.

Eu, particularmente, gosto muito do Mustache: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/. É um plugin bem simples e rápido.

Basicamente, você teria isso:

```
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{Propriedade1}}</td>
            <td>{{Propriedade2}}</td>
            <td>{{Propriedade3}}</td>
            <td>{{Propriedade4}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>

function renderTable() {
    // busca o template salvo na página
    var template = $('#template').html();

    // renderiza o template com o json
    var rendered = Mustache.render(template, json);

    // insere o HTML final dentro de um elemento
    $('#target').html(rendered);
}
```